# Database created through Entity Framwork 6 is not present in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am new to MVC and Entity Framework . I am using code first approach. So far I came to know that database is created automatically when the application run for the first time . I have created Model classes and wanted to populate data in the table through seed method . The sample application is working fine on browser but the database is not present in the SQL server.

```
 **************************CONTEXT**************************

 public class userInformationContext:DbContext
{
    public userInformationContextClass()
    {    
    }
    public DbSet<User> users { get; set; }

}
```

I have been looking for the issue over the internet but didn't got any solution.I am following this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674)! . Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just add correct connection string in web config. It will create the sql database on that server

```html
<add name="BloggingCompactDatabase" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;"/>
```

Comment: The database is created i.e why the application is running fine but it is not present in SQL server . Also when when I add connection string in web config file I gets exception to update my database with code first migration , which means that the database is already created and I don't want to use code first migration for this issue. I want to know why database is not present in SQL SERVER as well as in LOCAL DB.

Comment: Because by default EF uses LocalDb unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: For code first you need to enable migration or use intialization strategy as "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: thanks Matt... by default entity framework always create the mdf file using attachedb connection string using localdb but we need to change that based upon our requirement